# Saving several plots in r using plot and mfrow function

Tags: r

I have the question following. Let's say we have 9 columns of same data frame Q and time vector t. I want to plot for each of column of Q with respect to time i.e.

```
plot(t,Q[,1])
plot(t,Q[,2])
...
plot(t,Q[,9])
```

and I want to separate them into 4 subplots i.e. in first plot I have Q[,1]-Q[,4] and in the second one Q[,5]-Q[,8] and Q[,9] in the last one. At the end I want to have these 3 plots saved by using loop.

**My work so far**

```
par(mfrow=c(1,4)))
for (i in 1:length(Q)){
plot(Q[,1],Q[,i])
png(print(paste(i,".png")))
  dev.off()
  }
```

But it only saves all 9 graphs, and I don't have idea how can I write a loop which saves only 3 images I want.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose your data looks like this, with `t` as your first column and your variables in the next 9 columns (as seems likely from the second part of your question)

```r
set.seed(69)
Q <- data.frame(t = 1:10, replicate(9, cumsum(runif(10))))
```

If we want a new PNG for each four new images, we need to tell R that. First of all, we only want to iterate from column 2 to the last column (since our first column is `t`), so we need `for(i in 2:length(Q))`.

We also need to keep track of when a new plot should be drawn. This should be every 4 plots, so we need to call `png` when `i` is 2, 6, and 10. We can use the modulus operator `%%` to figure this out: we start a new png whenever `i %% 4 == 2`. Similarly, we want to do our `dev.off()` to save the plot whenever `i %% 4 == 1` or when we reach the last column. Remember `par()` is reset whenever you open a new device, so we have to do `par(mfrow = c(2, 2))` after each call to `png`

So the code will look something like this:

```
for(i in 2:length(Q))
{
  if(i %% 4 == 2) {
    png(paste0("plots_", i - 1, "_to_", i + 2, ".png"))
    par(mfrow = c(2, 2))
  }
  plot(Q[[1]], Q[[i]], type= "l", xlab = "time", ylab = paste("Variable", i - 1))
  if(i %% 4 == 1 | i == length(Q)) dev.off()
}
```

Now when I check in my R home directory, I find the following four files:

---

**plots_1_to_4.png**

---

[image]

---

**plots_5_to_8.png**

---

[image]

---

**plots_9_to_12.png**

[image]